# How to countdown days in android application?

Tags: android, countdown, days

Last day I tried to create a countdown for 77 days left. I did it, but the problem is that my countdown is working with milliseconds, and 77 days in milliseconds is exactly 6652800000, and the problem is that if I set my countdown with this value, it shows an error which says: The literal 6652800000 of type int is out of range. How to set it correctly to countdown from the present day to 77 days in the future? Thanks !

Here is my:

**MainActivity:**

```
package com.example.dasds;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv; //textview to display the countdown
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
tv = new TextView(this);
this.setContentView(tv);
//5000 is the starting number (in milliseconds)
//1000 is the number to count down each time (in milliseconds)
MyCount counter = new MyCount(6652800000,86400000);
counter.start();
}
//countdowntimer is an abstract class, so extend it and fill in methods
public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
tv.setText("Done");
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
tv.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished/86400000);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Java primitive types [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). In your case, a `long` will suffice.

Comment: And how to change it?

Comment: Also you can try with Joda time library, it will count day's instead of time.

Comment: I can't see how you declared your integer variables. Can you post them so I can tell you where to change? Typically, **millisUntilFinished** might need to be declared as a `long`.

Comment: But it is set as long here: `public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)`

Comment: Instead of hardcoding **6652800000** and **86400000** as parameters in your methods, I would pass/cast them to `long` variables, and use these variables instead, or use Salauyou's answer below if you don't want to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `L` right after number literal to cast it to `long`:

```
MyCount counter = new MyCount(6652800000L,86400000L);
```

Comment: That's perfect. Working perfect. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

```
int year = Integer.parseInt(year);
int month = Integer.parseInt(monthafter77days);
int day = 
Integer.parseInt(dateafter77days);
int hour = Integer.parseInt(hourneeded if );
int minute = Integer.parseInt(minuteneeded if);
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute);
/**
* Converting the date and time in to
* milliseconds elapsed since epoch
*/
long alarm_time = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
schedulealarm(alarm_time );
```

enjoy

Comment: I didn't get you idea on how to change it. Maybe you can be more specific? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try to cast the parameter values to long while calling MYCount constructor.

Comment: How do you suggest to do it?

Comment: MyCount counter = new MyCount(6652800000L,86400000L);

Answer (score 0):

try changing you onTick method as following. Android textviews tends to mess about when passed double and long values.

```
 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    tv.setText("Left: " + String.valueof(millisUntilFinished/86400000));
}
```

Comment: The value for one day is not wrong, the problem is at the value for 77 days.